# SWIG: How to merge a python file into the final module file generated by swig

Tags: python, c++, swig

As far as I know, in the .i file that for compiling c++ file to a python extension module, we could add some python code like following (example from [example for adding additional python code](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn42)):

```
/* Rewrite the high level interface to set_transform */
%pythoncode %{
def set_transform(im,x):
   a = new_mat44()
   for i in range(4):
       for j in range(4):
           mat44_set(a,i,j,x[i][j])
   _example.set_transform(im,a)
   free_mat44(a)
%}
```

Then, the python function appears in created python extension module.

If I have many python functions that I want to add them into created python module, what I could do ? I do not want to put all the python code into the

```
%pythoncode %{
...
%}
```

environment.

Thanks every body.

PS: What I want is to merge the context of a python file into the final .py module file generated by swig.

PSS: I found the resolution in the page [Comments in %pythoncode damaged #379](https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/379): use the statement `%pythoncode "x.py"` to import all the context of **x.py** into the final .py file generated by swig.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the code in another Python module, and then:

```
%pythoncode %{
import other
%}
```

Or if you want all the functions in that module in the extension's namespace:

```
%pythoncode %{
from other import *
%}
```

Comment: Thank you, at first. With your method, in the final  .py file, there is just the statement `import other` or `from other import *`. That means I still need module **other**. I just want the new module file .py and the respective *.so.

Comment: My environment: `SWIG Version 2.0.11` + `Ubuntu 14.04` + `Python 3.4.3`

Comment: I found the resolution, use the statement `%pythoncode "other.py"` to import all context of **other.py** into the final generated .py file.

Answer (score 1):

As per @xhao79 comment on another answer:

%pythoncode "other.py"

[Adding additional Python code](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn42)

> As an alternative to providing a block containing Python code, you can
>   include Python code from a file. The code is inserted exactly as in
>   the file, so this avoids any issues with the SWIG preprocessor. It's a
>   good approach if you have a non-trivial chunk of Python code to
>   insert.